# How to Run this API Request Using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, get, okta-api

I am very new to python and API Integration. Can anyone pls tell me how do I run this okta document using python?

> curl -v -X GET 
> -H "Accept: application/json" 
> -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
> -H "Authorization: SSWS ${api_token}" 
> "https://${yourOktaDomain}/api/v1/apps"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use urllib for do it.

Example:

```py
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

api_token = "..."
yourOktaDomain = "..."

headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Autorization": "SSWS " + api_token
}

request = Request("https://" + yourOktaDomain + "/api/v1/apps", headers=headers)
response = urlopen(request)
data = response.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests                                                         
import json


yourOktaDomain = 'something.okta.com'
api_token= ''

payload = ""
headers = {
    'Accept': "application/json",
    'Content-Type': "application/json",
    'Authorization': "SSWS "+api_token
    }
response1=requests.request("GET", 'https://'+{yourOktaDomain}+'/api/v1/apps', data=payload, headers=headers)
response1.json()
```